# Java Multidimensional array or some better solution?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm reading text from multiple links and want to have something similar to not so great example below. 
Each link would be stored as an ID, under each ID there are 3 Info's and each 'Info' has 2 'type' lists. What would be the best possible approach?
Examples are much appreciated.
[1][1][0][1] would give me [ID2][Info2][Type3][2nd element]

1. ID1 [[[[.,.,.,n]]]]

   - Info1 [[[0]]]

     - Type1 [[0]]

       - element[.,.,.,n]
     - Type2 [[1]]
   - Info2 [[[1]]]

     - Type3 [[0]]

       - element[.,.,.,n]
     - Type4 [[1]]

       - element[.,.,.,n]
   - Info3 [[[1]]]

     - Type5 [[0]]

       - element[.,.,.,n]
     - Type6 [[1]]

       - element[.,.,.,n]
2. ID2 [[[[.,.,.,n]]]]

   - Info1 [[[0]]]

     - Type1 [[0]]

       - element[.,.,.,n]
     - Type2 [[1]]
   - Info2 [[[1]]]

     - Type3 [[0]]

       - element[.,.,.,n]
     - Type4 [[1]]

       - element[.,.,.,n]

Answer (score -1):

That might be a mess. I would use XML or better yet, JSON. For example:

```
[
  {
      "id": 1,
      "info1": {
        "type1": ["a", "b"],
        "type2": ["c", "d"]
      },
      "info2": {
        "type1": ["e", "f"],
        "type2": ["g", "h"]
      },
      "info3": {
        "type1": ["i", "j"],
        "type2": ["k", "l"]
      }
  },
  {
      "id": 2,
      "info1": {
        "type1": ["a", "b"],
        "type2": ["c", "d"]
      },
      "info2": {
        "type1": ["e", "f"],
        "type2": ["g", "h"]
      },
      "info3": {
        "type1": ["i", "j"],
        "type2": ["k", "l"]
      }
  }
]
```

You can parse this with a suitable JSON library to get nice Java objects to access the data without having to worry about a million indexes.

Comment: I dont think this is an answer